# SSIS package tasks copy paste and keep connection manager name

Tags: ssis, dataflow

I have some larger SSIS package processes I wrote in a test package and I want to copy/past it into an existing package.  I have connection managers in both packages that have the same name.  When I copy from one package to the other, it creates a new connection manager but with a "1" at the end of it.

Is there a way to have it NOT do this and just use the existing package connection manager with the same name?

Otherwise I will have to go into all the tasks, update the connection manager, and in places it resets the tables I was inserting into and I will have to redo all that as well.

Any suggestions?

Also is there anyway to update a variable name in many tasks easily?  I just want to rename a variable but dont want to have to go in and edit every task to do so.

Comment: Edit the packages XML and make sure they have the same ID.

Comment: The problem is that a connection manager is really unique based on a unique ID that is assigned to it (e.g. a GUID) when you are copying even though they have the same name they have a different GUID so it creates the new connection and then modifies the name to make that unique.  As MXIX suggests you can edit the xml, but if the package you are copying into is not using that connection manager or for less perhaps delete it before you copy the other part over?

Comment: Are you able to upgrade the packages to project deployment and use project connections and project parameters instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a project level connection manager instead of using package level connection manager.
Right click on **Connection Manager** in solution explorer and create the connection manager. This connection manager will be common to all the packages. You can change the tables for this connection manager where you are using it. For all packages it will point to same database.
[image: Package1 with Project level connection]

As you can see in below snapshot PackageLevel_ConManager is not visible, but Project level is visible in both the snapshot. 
[image: Package2 with project level connection]